# Link between device state & user settable root of trust

Tags: security, boot

I am (still) trying to understand exactly how verified boot works and I am wondering what happens when a user-settable root of trust is used by the device.
As said [here](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/device-state):

> If the device is LOCKED, the bootloader goes through the steps in
>   Verifying Boot to verify the device's software. LOCKED devices boot
>   only if the loaded OS is properly signed by the root of trust. For
>   more details, see The boot flow.

- Does the fact of setting a user-settable root of trust imply that
  the device has to be UNLOCKED?
- Does it mean that a LOCKED device can
  boot on a custom OS if it is signed with the user-settable root of
  trust?
- Is the warning still displayed if the user-settable root of
  trust is used to validate tue boot process?

Answer (score 0):

- Custom root of trust has to be set from fastboot according to docs. The OEM can implement it in different ways, the docs recommend that a custom certificate can only be installed from UNLOCKED state
- Once your certificate is installed as root of trust, you can boot in LOCKED mode (only binaries signed by either you or the OEM will be allowed to boot)
- Following the docs, a warning should be displayed if booting a custom signed firmware (booting the OEM signed one shouldn't ?)